# output net view (batch) into text then perform action against each computer

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to find away to search for the existence of my company's software on PC's by searching hostnames on the network `\\computername\c$\Program Files\Foo`, and if it finds it, copy over an updated config etc.

I've seen that `net view` will out put all the PC's on the network, something like this:

> ```
> \\DISKSTATION
> \\JWLAPTOP
> \\TEST
> \\XP
> The command completed successfully.
> ```

I was wondering if there was a way to just get the computer names in a clean list (without "command completed" etc.):

> ```
> \\DISKSTATION
> \\JWLAPTOP
> \\TEST
> \\XP
> ```

Then run some commands against it, for everything in `hostnames.txt`, if exist:

> ```
> \\JWLAPTOP\c$\Program Files\Foo --> do copy xyz to wherever
> ```

I can take care of the part `\c$\Program Files\Foo` as a variable to add after the computer names in the text file.

Hope that makes sense, thanks for any tips.
*edit*

Been re thinking this perhaps there is a more direct way to do this....

I need to see the list of PC's on customers network.....net view is a good way of getting this info so far, but I further need to see which ones are online. Any online, query for folder and update a *.CFG file, any offline, output to text for reference.

So at the minute....

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%G IN ('net view ^|findstr /L /B /C:"\\"')
```

this is working great, I then made it output to a text file..

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%G IN ('net view ^|findstr /L /B /C:"\\"') DO (echo %%G>>%~dp0netview.txt)
```

However, the %%G echo's back \somecomputer which means I am struggling to get a new line..

`for /f %%G in (%~dp0netview.txt) DO` (ping etc......

to ping because of the \ before the computer name. So was wonder if we can make the list 'just" have the PC name without the \ before it.

Also this is the content of the .cfg file I need to edit...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClientConfigurationFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ServerPath>**\\server\shared\data**</ServerPath>
  <ApplicationMode>Workstation</ApplicationMode>
  <VRPath />
  <ServicePollingInterval>0</ServicePollingInterval>
</ClientConfigurationFile>
```

perhaps there is a way of editing a certain section of this directly once its existence is found.  **\server\shared\data**...in bold is what I need to update often when clients have new servers and things and involves having to go round lots of rooms to update manually. This batch could save hours upon hours of unnecessary work.

over writing the existing .cfg file is still a good way of doing it if it's too tricky or not possible directly.

Hope it makes sense, thanks for the replies!!!

Comment: It's not a good idea to change the scope of a question, as any existing answers might no longer apply; it's better to ask a new question then...

Comment: To remove leading backslashes, do something like: `for /F "tokens=* delims=\" %%T in ("\computerame") do echo %%T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming none of your computer names have spaces in them.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%G IN ('net view ^|findstr /L /B /C:"\\"') DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~G\c$\Program Files\Foo" copy "C:\folder\xyz.txt" "C:\other folder\"
)
```

If you want the leading back slashes stripped then use it as a delimiter just like I am using the space as a delimiter to get rid of all the extraneous NET VIEW output.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=\ " %%G IN ('net view ^|findstr /L /B /C:"\\"') DO (
    PING %%G
    IF EXIST "\\%%~G\c$\Program Files\Foo" copy "C:\folder\xyz.txt" "C:\other folder\"
)
```

Comment: @aschipfl - Thanks Much.

Comment: This is working great, but I've found another requirement. Is there a way to strip the \\ from the computer name. I was think of running ping tests against the host name and only applying file copy if it's online, and any offline being out put to a text file.  I've got this FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%G IN ('net view ^|findstr /L /B /C:"\\"') DO (echo %%G>>%~dp0netview.txt)
:start

for /f %%G in (%~dp0netview.txt) DO (...........but of course the %%g has the \\ infront of the name so wont ping, thanks!!!

Comment: @Tika9o9, please put your additional requirements in your original question.  Putting that much code into a comment is very hard to read.

Comment: @Tika9o9, have you ever heard of scope creep!  Now you have added on yet another additional requirement to your script.  Every time you add on an additional requirement, it could in theory drastically change the code. I added code above to remove the back slash from the computer name.  That is as far as I am going to take it. I am not sure why you would need to ping the computer to see if it is online. If the administrative share does not EXIST then you know it is not online.

Comment: thanks, just googled scope creep and expected to find a tool to do what I was looking for LOL. I get it, keep on track. The new code is great, will get some good use out it. I just need to generate text where the file copied ok and where perhaps it didnt. This is because I need the PC's on to do the changes and often clients assure me all the appropriate machines are, when they arent, so would be good to have some log of what happened to prove it when required. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "TARGET=C$\Program Files\Foo"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%C in ('
    net view ^| find "\\"
') do (
    pushd "%%C\%TARGET%"
    if not ErrorLevel 1 (
        rem do your operations here...
        copy "\your\source\path\xyz" "."
        popd
    )
)
endlocal
```

The `for /F` loop walks through all host names returned by `net view` (supposing each one starts with `\\` and there are *only* the host names).
Since the resulting path (for instance `\\TEST\C$\Program Files\Foo`) is a UNC path which is not supported by several commands, `pushd` is used, which is capable of connecting to the given resource by establishing a temporary drive letter like `Z:`, and changing the working directory to its root immediately (if the command extensions are on, which is the Windows default).
The query `if not ErrorLevel 1` is used to skip over the remaining commands in case `pushd` could not connect to the resource for some reason.
After all your operations, `popd` ensures that the temporary drive created by `pushd` is unmounted and that the former working directory is restored.

Comment: @Tika9o9, in this code it is testing if it can attach to the target before it copies the file.